# Detect duplicated items within a Python array

Tags: python, for-loop

**simplifying python**
I am trying to check if any 2 variables in an array are equal, how do i simplify this? I would like to simplify this to be a for loop, this is what i have tried.

```
if check[0] == check[1]:
   print('you win!!')
else:
   print('you lost!')
if check[0] == check [2]:
  print('you win!!')
else:
  print('you lost!')
if check [1]==check[2]:
  print('you win!!')
else:
  print('you lost!')
```

Comment: You might start by looking at `itertools`.

Comment: Or, even better, instead of doing pairwise comparisons, think about using accumulators. If you have a `defaultdict(lambda: 0)` where you iterate over `check` and increment values, then you only need to look at whether there's any value in the resulting map that's greater than 1.

Comment: BTW, when asking a question here, please try to focus on the _specific technical problem itself_, not the context in which you encountered that problem. I've edited the title towards that end.